# Converting exsisting Android project to Kindle

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, kindle, kindle-fire

I have an existing android project which is available in the Android market. Is it possible to convert that to be work in Kindle? I have no idea about Kindle and when searching I found that it can run android apps.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

All the information you need is [right here](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html), as a quick search would have told you.

Answer (score 3):

The Kindle Fire is currently the only Kindle that can run Android apps, since it is more of a tablet than an e-reader.  You can find information on optimizing your app to run on the Kindle Fire here: https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html?ref_=pe_132830_21362890#KindleFire